# pass dictionary to clientside

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I recieved dictionary at client side that contains the following structure

```
Dictionary<string,List<QuestionPropertyValue>> inputMap = new Dictionary<string,List<QuestionPropertyValue>>();
List<QuestionPropertyValue> questions = new List<QuestionPropertyValue>();
questions.Add(new QuestionPropertyValue(){QuestionName="USINSTR0208",PropertyName="Value",Value="Yes"});
inputMap.Add("key1", questions);
```

How can I find questions for "key1" at client side ?

when I debuged I found the dictionary is converted to object that contain list of objects each one contains list of questions and when I googled I found that dictionary became associative array at client side but I cannot search for that at all.

All ideas are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`Item` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84k9x471%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the Dictionary interface to get the associated item:

```
var d = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary");

d.Add('a', 'foo');
d.Add('b', [1, 2, 3]);

d.Item('a'); // => "foo"
d.Item('b'); // => [1,2,3]
d.Item('b')[0]; // => 1
```

In your example it looks like you can do this:

```
var questions = inputMap.Item('key1');
questions[0]; // => QuestionPropertyValue[QuestionName="USINSTR0208"...]
```

Comment: thanks man but I want to get list if questions using the key name .it something like that var questions=dic.contains("key1"); I want to get evaluation for this

Comment: @thabet084: gotcha, see my entirely new answer.